# Library MPDF (PHP): Problems converting svg

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js, svg, mpdf

I have html content that need to convert to pdf. It includes basic html, use of external css and svg elements generated with the D3 library (javascript).

For the conversion I use the MPDF (php) library. I get errors in the svg export.

An example of a troubled chart. Here the original html:
[image: image 1]

Performing the export like this:

```
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($footer);
    
    $cont_format = utf8_decode($content);
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($cont_format );

    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($file);
```

This bad pdf is obtained:
[image: svg]

Then converting the svg to base 64 in javascript, like this:

```
tags_svg = $('svg');
tags_svg.each(function(indice){
        html = $(this).prop('outerHTML');

        imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(html)));
        img = '<img src="'+imgsrc+'"';
        attributes = $(this).prop("attributes");
        $.each(attributes, function() {
            img += ' '+this.name+'="'+this.value+'"';
        });
        img += ' />';

        $(this).html(img);
});
```

Improve the output, but it is not quite the same as the original:
[image: base 64]

What is missing for interpret the base 64 image correctly? Why wouldn't some styles be respecting them?
If it is opened in the browser the url in base 64 is seen correctly.
Any ideas to improve the result?

Thanks!

Comment: An image can't have external CSS so you'd need to convert that into something internal first e.g. a data URL.

Comment: @RobertLongson external css is for other elements. Image genere with D3, with explicit css like this:  d3.selectAll('.month')
 .style({
  "fill": "none",
  "stroke": "#000",
  "stroke-width": "2px"
 });